# strongly continuous semi-groups integration

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a Banach space. Define $T:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbf{B}(V)$ such that $T_{s + t} = T_s T_t$, $T_0 = I$, and $t \mapsto T_t v$ is norm continuous for every $v \in V$. I am a bit confused about this, given $f$ continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and $v \in V$, we can define $$\int_0^t f(s) T_sv ds$$with $f(s)T_sv$ is a norm continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^+$[defined by Riemann integral]. The only types of integrals that I have seen are the Lebesgue integral and real number Riemann integral. I did some searching, and I think have Riemann integrals with Banach spaces. Is this what he is doing here? The reason why my professor wrote this is to show that this integral is in $D(A)$ where $D(A)$ is the domain of $A$ i.e. $Av := \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{T_{t + h}v - T_tv}{h}$

Comment: Yes, you can generalize the Riemann integral to Banach spaces. See also the Bochner integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral